# For Uiimageview how to set the CGgradient background colour as background colour in ios swift4?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, gradient, cagradientlayer

```
var navigationImageView:UIImageView! = UIImageView()
navigationImageView.frame = (0,0,320,64)

var gradient = CAGradientLayer()
let gradientDark = UIColor(red: 148/255.0, green:210/255.0, blue: 245/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let gradientLight = UIColor(red: 222/255.0, green:247/255.0, blue: 230/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let gradientLight1 = UIColor(red: 245/255.0, green:247/255.0, blue: 206/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
gradient.frame = navigationImageView.bounds

let color1 = gradientDark.cgColor
let color2 = gradientLight.cgColor
let color3 = gradientLight1.cgColor

gradient.colors = [color1, color2, color3]

gradient.colors = [gradientDark.cgColor,gradientLight.cgColor,gradientLight1.cgColor];

navigationImageView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

Its not working... How to se the cgradient image backgorund colour?

Comment: Is your image a png ?? Your image has to be a transparent if you wanna see the gradient added to imageView else loaded image will hide the gradient added else add the gradient as top layer to imageView

Comment: The image is in png

Comment: you want to set image and gradient or only gradient? and you want to set gradient in navigation so i can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make image from gradient and set it in `imageView`

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
let defaultNavigationBarFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: 64)
gradient.frame = defaultNavigationBarFrame

//colors
let gradientDark = UIColor(red: 148/255.0, green:210/255.0, blue: 245/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let gradientLight = UIColor(red: 222/255.0, green:247/255.0, blue: 230/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let gradientLight1 = UIColor(red: 245/255.0, green:247/255.0, blue: 206/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

gradient.colors = [gradientDark.cgColor,gradientLight.cgColor,gradientLight1.cgColor]
// Create image.
let imageBG: UIImage = self.gradientImage(fromLayer: gradient)
```

If you want to set it in navigation bar.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(imageBG,
                                                                for: .default)
```

Create image from gradient.

```
func gradientImage(fromLayer layer: CALayer) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layer.frame.size)

    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

    let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return outputImage!
}
```

Comment: this method is not working..Its crashing in inside the gradientImage function